# How to use Google Input Tool in Google Chrome's Omni bar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, non-english, google-input-tools

I would like to use the google input tool to search in a non-English language from Google Chrome's omni bar or type a part of an URL in a non-English language. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only available in `Chrome OS`

[image]

https://www.google.com/inputtools/chrome/chrome-os.html

Maybe you can UpVote this issue:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/156075816